# Regex to redirect any url ending in ?layout=mobi or ?layout=full to homepage

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

Changed my site to wordpress. Used to have mobile and full site options where ?layout=mobi or ?layout=full would call on those files.

Now getting lots of 404s in WMT for example.com/page1.html?layout=mobi

I'm looking for regex to just redirect all 404s that end in ?layout=full or ?layout=mobi to the homepage of the site so that these 404s don't clog up my WMT.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way, to check first `RewriteCond` on `QUERY_STRING` before apply `RewriteRule` that redirects to your homepage

```
RewriteEngine On
# Check if the query string contains layout=mobi OR layout=full
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(layout=mobi|layout=full)$
RewriteRule ^example.com/page1.html$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```